# How to set UIImage to UITableView Cell which calculates cell height dynamically based on text I input in UILabel?

Tags: uitableview, uiimageview, uilabel, cgrect

I am creating UITableView, where each cell size will b calculated based on the text I input.
I am Calculating size of Cell in heighForRowAtIndexPath

```
- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath;
{
    NSString *text = [tableData objectAtIndex:[indexPath row]];

    CGSize constraint = CGSizeMake(210.0f, 20000.0f);
    size = [text sizeWithFont:[UIFont systemFontOfSize:12.0f] constrainedToSize:constraint lineBreakMode:UILineBreakModeWordWrap];

    height = MAX(size.height, 44.0f);

    return height + (CCM * 2);
}
```

this is how I am calculating height for each cell, now my question is - I want to add image to each cell like comment box? like this
[Click here to see comment boxes I am looking for](http://2.s3.envato.com/files/149908.jpg)

You can see these kind of comment boxes
what I did is I made my image into two parts
first one has top part which is working well on every cell starting image is coming
now while fixing bottom part me facing problem
for small text in cell UILable its working well
when size of text in UILabel increased it's not getting properly adjusted

```
-(UITableViewCell *) tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    NSString *identifier = @"cell";

    NSLog(@"index path %d", indexPath.row);

    MyTableCell *cell = (MyTableCell *)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:identifier];

    if (cell == nil) 
    {
        cell = [[[MyTableCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:identifier] autorelease];
        cell.selectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone;
    }

    [cell.cellBackgroundBottom setFrame:CGRectMake(75.0f, 92.0f, 228.0f, height + 25.0f)];

    [cell.cellContent setText:(NSString*)[tableData objectAtIndex:[indexPath row]]];
    [cell.cellContent sizeToFit];

    CGRect theFrame = [cell.cellContent frame];
    theFrame.size.width = 210.0f;
    [cell.cellContent setFrame: theFrame];

    return cell;
}
```

I have created one UITableView subclass naming MYTableCell where I have defined what all I need inside my each cell.

```
 // Creating UILabel for cell content or comments block

        cellContent = [[UILabel alloc]initWithFrame: CGRectMake( 90.0f, 15.0f, 210.0f, 60.0f)] ;
        [cellContent setLineBreakMode:UILineBreakModeWordWrap];
        cellContent.numberOfLines = 0;
        [cellContent setMinimumFontSize:15.0f];
        [cellContent setBackgroundColor:[UIColor clearColor]];
        //   [cellContent setTextColor:[UIColor colorWithRed:73.0f green:73.0f blue:73.0f alpha:1.0f]];
        [cellContent setFont:[UIFont fontWithName:@"Helvetica" size:12.0f]];
        cellContent.textAlignment = UITextAlignmentLeft;
        [cellContent setTag:1];
        [self addSubview:cellContent];
        [cellContent release];

        cellBackgroundTop = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(60.0f, 5.0f, 243.0f, 13.5f)];
        [cellBackgroundTop setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"comments.png"]];
        [self addSubview:cellBackgroundTop];
        [cellBackgroundTop release];

        cellBackgroundBottom = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectZero];
        [cellBackgroundBottom setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"Untitled-1_09.png"]];
        [self addSubview:cellBackgroundBottom];
        [cellBackgroundBottom release];
```

Answer (score 0):

I got answer for my question
. This is what i have to do in my cellForRowAtIndexPath

```
 NSString *text = [tableData objectAtIndex:[indexPath row]];

    CGSize constraint = CGSizeMake(210.0f, 20000.0f);

    CGSize size1 = [text sizeWithFont:[UIFont systemFontOfSize:12.0f] constrainedToSize:constraint lineBreakMode:UILineBreakModeWordWrap];

    CGFloat height1 = MAX(size1.height, 44.0f);

    [cell.cellBackgroundBottom setFrame:CGRectMake(75.0f, 18.0f, 228.0f, height1 + 10.0f)];
```